# Accessing HttpContext in Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, saas

I am trying to build a multi-tenant application, where based on the user email, they will be mapped to different resources (database, redis, blob storage and application insights). The details of connection string will be available in separate key vaults. one key vault per tenant.

So when the API is called, based on the logged in users email, we should call a catalog service and fetch the key vault details and load it using AddAzureKeyVault. Is this possible. I am not able to access HttpContext when the web application is built. It is available only later. are they any other options?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

//Get Keyvault by calling external API and passing the JWT token from header
var keyVault = GetKeyVaultFromExternalAPI();
builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri($"https://{keyVault}.vault.azure.net"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

I am thinking of using a middleware, which will update the configuration, but not sure, how it can update the redis connection string or Application Insights connection.

Comment: At that point in the process, there is no request being handled, there is no user. The only way you can configure the AzureKeyVault that way is if you have a separate installation for each tenant, and it's the installation that determines the tenant, not the user.

Comment: This being a multi-tenant application, the web app will be shared across tenants. So separate installation for each tenant is ruled out.. So changing the configuration in middleware or creating the instance (of dbcontext or rediscache) later in request cycle seems to be the only options.

Comment: I assumed as much, making the point that this is not going to work and you need to come up with something entirely different.

Comment: Do you know all the tenants at startup? You can probably map secrets to different configuration prefixes, via a custom `KeyVaultSecretManager`, similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-8.0#use-a-key-name-prefix ? Then you can probably use the tenant name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0#named-options-support-using-iconfigurenamedoptions ? But running separate processes would be simpler.

Comment: Since you aren't sharing database, redis, application insights. Why share a web server process? You could run a kubernetes cluster, with a deployment per tenant, setting the tenant name as an environment variable. But otherwise running the same container image for the web server. Running behind a single nginx Ingress proxy.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks for the inputs, I will try that option as well